# Email-enabled library receiving messages but metadata not populating into columns

Tags: 2010, document-library, email-enabled-library

I have an email-enabled document library in SharePoint 2010 that is receiving the emails, but the metadata columns ("E-Mail From", "E-Mail Subject", etc) are not being populated. The original emails are being saved, and I can open them with a text editor and see the data is there.

Here are my incoming email settings:

> - Save all attachments in folders grouped by e-mail subject
> - Overwrite files with the same name: No
> - Save original e-mail: Yes
> - Accept e-mail messages from any sender

I saved the library as a template without content, created a new one, and duplicated the above settings, but with a different email address. Everything worked on the new one.

Short of deleting and re-creating the list, how can I fix the email-enabled list so that the metadata columns properly populate?

Comment: did you ever find out what the problem was, have the same issue on a library. when i create a new library in the same web and re-use (after deactivation at the other place) the email address it works in the new list. Recreating the list from the template didn't solve it for me.

Comment: @Shihan, no, the solution was to create a new list and use that one.